# Getting error while saving morphia model to mongodb using CRUD interface

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

During generic save action of morphia model using CRUD interface I recieve following error:

> Oops: NullPointerException An unexpected error occured caused by
> exception NullPointerException: null
>
> play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error     at
> play.modules.morphia.Model.edit(Model.java:219)   at
> play.modules.morphia.MorphiaPlugin.bind(MorphiaPlugin.java:607)
> ...

I've found that similiar error was in version 1.2.4a and was fixed in 1.2.4b.
I downoladed the latest version of morphia. On app start I recieve followind log:

> 12:18:59,036 INFO  ~ Module morphia is available (C:\play-1.2.4\samples-and-tests\test1\modules\ **morphia-1.2.4b** )
>
> 12:18:59,037 INFO  ~ Module secure is available (C:\play-1.2.4\modules\secure)
>
> 12:18:59,978 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
>
> 12:19:00,110 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...
>
> 12:19:11,680 INFO  ~ Connected to jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
>
> 12:19:14,869 INFO  ~ **MorphiaPlugin-1.2.4a**> initialized

So, now I can't understad what version of morphia I actually use and can't understand how to fix the error.

Please, advice me something about my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem, in this day morphia doesn't work with play `1.2.4` crud module. You have to rollback to `1.2.3`.